# laravel group by and select sum of one of many relation

Tags: laravel, group-by, eloquent, sum

I have a model (product) that uses an one of many realation (price), and I try to get top x users with sum of product prices. A user has many products.

So somehow I need `products` to `group by 'user_id'` and select the sum of `price` of each product the user has, so that finally I get a list with user_id and sum('product.price').

I guess I need to manually join the `prices` table

the has one of many relation:

```
return $this->hasOne(Price::class)
    ->ofMany([
        'valid_from' => 'max',
        'id' => 'max',
    ], function ($query) {
        $query->where('valid_from', '<=', Carbon::now());
    });
```

I can accomplish this with collections, but is it possible in Eloquent?